# Call javascript function when certain page is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a function that collects forecast information from a certain website. When I am on the website and call the function from the console of Chrome Browser it works perfectly. However, I want to automate the process and call the function whenever this certain webpage is loaded. I thought of building a Chrome extension but I am new to this. So is there any possible way to attach a JS function to the browser? I don't own the webpage so I can only access its information from the DevTools of Chrome. Sorry if it's a duplicate topic but I couldn't find one that answers my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just put the function in a script tag on that page and call it?

Comment: Because it's a public page (i don't own it).

Comment: You could try to use an iFrame for this?  ( this would allow you to call the public page and your code )  Some sites will not work in iFrame.

Comment: you could try to use a bookmarklet - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154 and  http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally done/organized.

Comment: See: [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). In addition to making a full extension to do this (a relatively easy thing to do), there are many alternate ways to have a user script for a page.  There are a variety of extensions which exist whose purpose is to allow you to run small user scripts on specific pages without the need to make a complete extension for each one.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are making a chrome extension, you can use background.js to inject a script into the webpage

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'inject_script.js'
});
```

And inside your script, you can write the javascript code (`onload event`) to execute this script on page load.

Also for this you'll have to add permission `tabs` in your manifest and the following code in your manifest.json :

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
  }
```

See [background_pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

Comment: this is not the recommended way. read about content scripts.